# how to get the product details in amazon mws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Hi here is my code please check it and let me know what im missing.
im using amazon orders API for this.

```
<?php

require_once('.config.inc.php');

//$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";
// Europe
$serviceUrl = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";
// Japan
//$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.jp/Orders/2013-09-01";
// China
//$serviceUrl = "https://mws.amazonservices.com.cn/Orders/2013-09-01";


 $config = array (
   'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
   'ProxyHost' => null,
   'ProxyPort' => -1,
   'ProxyUsername' => null,
   'ProxyPassword' => null,
   'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
 );

 $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Client(
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        APPLICATION_NAME,
        APPLICATION_VERSION,
        $config);


 $request = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrdersRequest();
 $request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
 // object or array of parameters
 echo"<pre>";
 print_r($service);
 invokeListOrders($service, $request);

  function invokeListOrders(MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Interface $service, $request)
  {
      try {
        $response = $service->ListOrders($request);

        echo ("Service Response\n");
        echo ("=============================================================================\n");

        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        echo $dom->saveXML();
        echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");

     } catch (MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Exception $ex) {
        echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
        echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
        echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
        echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
        echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
        echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
     }
 }
```

This is the XMl im using for getting the details i request somebody to reply me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add these two lines after the

$request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);

after this line add these two lines.

```
$request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);
$request->setCreatedAfter('2016-04-01');
```

Hope this helps..